# reading Unix wild card filenames from command line in Python

Tags: python, shell, unix, command-line, optparse

What's the correct way to handle Unix style wildcard arguments using `optparse` in Python? I have:

```
myscript.py:

from optparse import OptionParser
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("--input", dest="input", default=None, nargs=1)
parser.add_option("--outdir", dest="outdir", default=None, nargs=1)
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

I want to be able to do:

`myscript.py --input *.txt --outdir mydir/`

I don't want to necessarily read the contents of all the files matching `*.txt`. I want `myscript.py` to access their filenames, because some scripts just pass on the filenames to other programs without needing to open/read the files. How can I get an iterator that returns the filenames, while still allowing other arguments like `--outdir` to be passed after the wildcard friendly option (in this case `--input`)? thanks.

Comment: Do you take into account that UNIX shells will expand this glob themselves?

Comment: @wRAR if they expand it, does it mean that I get passed in a list of filenames? If *.txt was always translated to a.txt,b.txt,... etc there would be no problem. But I don't think that this is what happens

Comment: Yes, it will be expanded to a space-separated list of filenames.

Comment: Note: Using *optparse* is discouraged since python version 2.7. The optparse module is deprecated and will not be developed further; development will continue with the *argparse* module. See [PEP 0389](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0389/) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Unix shells will expand `*.txt` into separate arguments before they are passed to your program; Windows' command interpreter will not.

Assuming you're using an environment where they aren't expanded first -- that is, invoking `python prog.py '*.txt'`, for instance, you can use [glob.glob()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to do the expansion yourself.

Comment: It's unusual to require single quotes though.. I want my program to work like other unix utilities. Like `wc *.txt`. Also parsing it with glob seems complicated - what if I get passed in a filename that has `*` in it? How can I tell if it's a glob to be expanded or part of the filename?